need help - htaccess URL rewrite with query string
Disclaimer: I'm a semi-skilled novice, I've tried a few things but I'm missing something. My site is running a vBulletin Forum and nothing else. I recently upgraded my vBulletin version and moved the website to a new VPS/cPanel setup and now I need some help with a Google-friendly URL rewrite to fix my broken inbounds
The original URLs were https://www.mywebsite.com/forums/... (forums is plural) I no longer use the "forums" directory but can create one if that's a good place for an htaccess file specific for this task.
The "forum" in the new URLs is singular like https://www.mywebsite.com/forum/... there are also some changes after the /forum/ but I'm not sure if they matter since the target of the rewrite doesn't need them, it's the the NUMERIC topic ID embedded in the URLs that's needed
Any inbounds to the current URL format https://www.mywebsitet.com/forum/... with the singular "forum" are good and don't need a rewrite
Here are two examples of old URLs that need rewrites
https://www.mywebsite.com/forums/canon/176449-canon-ir-adv-dx-c5850-e355-003-error.html needs to be rewritten with a google friendly redirect to https://www.mywebsite.com/showthread.php?t=176449
https://www.mywebsite.com/forums/kyocera-mita-copystar/71926-fs-3900-dn-printer.html needs to be rewritten to https://www.mywebsite.com/showthread.php?t=71926
I've tried a bunch of things to query the numeric topic ID and use it for the rewrite but I can't seem to get the syntax correct. Any help would be appreciated.
